# DB operation, Is it very expensive?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table called `playlist`, and I display those details using `display_playlist.php` file.
screen shot of `display_playlist.php`:

[image]

Every time user clicks the 'up' or 'down' button to arrange the song order, I just update the table.But I feel updating DB very often is not recommended, so Is there any efficient way to accomplish this task.

I am still a newbie to AJAX, so if AJAX is the only way to do it, can you please explain it in detail.thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relative terms, yes, hitting the database is an expensive operation.  However, if the playlist state is meant to be persistent then you have to hit the database at some point, it's just a question of when/how often.

One simple optimization you might try is instead of sending each change the user makes to the server right away, allow them to make however many changes they want (using some client-side javascript to keep the UI in the correct state) and provide a "Save Playlist" button that they can press to submit all of their changes to the server at once.  That will reduce database hits, and also the number of round-trips made to the server (in terms of what a user experiences, a round-trip to the server is far more expensive than a database hit).

More broadly though, you shouldn't get hung up over hypothetical performance concerns.  Is your application too slow to handle its current load (and if so, have you done any profiling to verify that it is indeed this database query that is causing the issue)?  If not, then you don't need to worry too much about changing it just yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a save button, so instead of updating on each move there will only be one update where you update every row at one time.  This also lets you have a cancel button for people to refresh the way it was.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it so users can change locally all they wish; defer writing the final result to the database until they choose to move on from the page.

Comment: In additional, Putting something like "autosave" every some period will help unintended leave (of the page).

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to avoid updating the database, you can try some JavaScript based  MP3players , which allow you to pass the path to *.mp3 files.

Then I suggest you to use [Jquery UI - Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

and use it to update the songs list to the flash player ..